# Addressing 'Allowed Memory Size' Error When Merging Arrays or Collections"

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

How can I refactor this code to optimize memory usage while ensuring that the 'order_number' remains unique throughout the list? Additionally, I want to save the final result in a JSONB column without encountering out-of-memory errors ?

```
public function generateRandomOrders(int $numbers): array
{
    $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
    $orders = [];
    for($i=0; $i < $numbers;$i++) {
        $order = [
            'discount' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 100),
            'order_amount' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 10, 1000),
            'order_amount_no_vat' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 10, 1000),
            'order_name' => $faker->words(3, true),
            'order_number' => $faker->unique()->randomNumber(),
            'payment_method' => $faker->creditCardType(),
            'shipping_cost' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 50),
            'status' => $faker->randomElement(['pending', 'processing', 'completed']),
            'tag_date' => $faker->date(),
            'tag_time' => $faker->time(),
            'vat_amount' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 50),
            'vat_percent' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 25),
        ];
        $orders[] = $order;
    }
    return $orders;
}

public function test(): JsonResponse
{
    ini_set('memory_limit','32M'); // intentionally reduce the memory limit to test memory overflow case
    $orders = collect([]);
    for($i=0; $i < 20;$i++) {
        $orders = $orders->merge($this->generateRandomOrders(5000)); // generate random 5000 orders
    }

    $cachedList = CachedList::firstOrNew([
        'company_id' => $this->company_id,
        'class' => get_class($this)
    ]);

    $cachedList->company_id = $this->company_id;
    $cachedList->data = $orders->unique('order_number')->values()->toArray(); // saving the final data in jsonb column
    $cachedList->class = get_class($this);
    $cachedList->save();
    return response()->json($orders);
}
```

Comment: *"I want to save the final result in a JSONB column"* You want to store 100K orders in a single row? Really? Consider saving to a file instead.

Comment: *"while ensuring that the 'order_number' remains unique throughout the list"* In a real-world scenario, why wouldn't `order_number` be unique?

Comment: MongoDB limits individual JSON document sizes to 16mb. The reasoning is that it's usually an indication that you are doing something contraindicated if you want to store larger documents. Maybe you need to review your overall approach

Comment: `'order_number' remains unique` there are less likely chances of `order_number` not being unique via the `random()`. But if still want to do it, you can use an hashmap and keep generating a random number against the hashmap and once you get an unique one add it to the hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating all orders in memory and then saving, you can generate and save them in chunks, avoiding the need to hold the entire dataset in memory at once.

```php
public function generateRandomOrders(int $numbers): array
{
    $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
    $orders = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numbers; $i++) {
        $order = [
            'discount' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 100),
            'order_amount' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 10, 1000),
            'order_amount_no_vat' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 10, 1000),
            'order_name' => $faker->words(3, true),
            'order_number' => $faker->unique()->randomNumber(),
            'payment_method' => $faker->creditCardType(),
            'shipping_cost' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 50),
            'status' => $faker->randomElement(['pending', 'processing', 'completed']),
            'tag_date' => $faker->date(),
            'tag_time' => $faker->time(),
            'vat_amount' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 50),
            'vat_percent' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 25),
        ];

        $orders[] = $order;
    }
    return $orders;
}

public function test(): JsonResponse
{
    ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');
    $chunkSize = 1000; // chunk size
    $totalOrders = 20 * $chunkSize;

    $cachedList = CachedList::firstOrNew([
        'company_id' => $this->company_id,
        'class' => get_class($this),
    ]);

    $cachedList->company_id = $this->company_id;
    $cachedList->class = get_class($this);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $totalOrders; $i += $chunkSize) {
        $chunkOrders = $this->generateRandomOrders($chunkSize);
        $orders = collect($chunkOrders)->unique('order_number')->values()->toArray();

        if ($i === 0) {
            // first chunk, directly set the data
            $cachedList->data = $orders;
        } else {
            // subsequent chunks, merge with existing data
            $cachedList->data = array_merge($cachedList->data, $orders);
        }

        // save the data after each chunk
        $cachedList->save();
    }

    return response()->json($cachedList->data);
}
```